# Cordova iOS File API - Move Photo to a persistent storage

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins, fileapi

I've a problem with moving a camera photo to the persistent storage under iOS 7 (Cordova 3.4.0-0.1.3 - File API 1.0.1).

I can capture the photo and when I move the file to the persistent storage it seems that there is no error, I also receive a file path with `new_entry.fullPath` like /my_folder/12345678.jpg.

But when I append the new image to the body with that url it seems that there is no image (blank image will be added). I've tried it also with "file://" in the url, but this makes no difference.

I'm also a little bit confused, because the `new_entry.toURL()` method returned an url containing a folder named "temporary" (e.g. cdvfile://localhost/temporary/my_folder/12345678.jpg), but I use the persistent storage. Is that correct under iOS?

This is my relevant code for that function:

```
var app = {
    capturePhoto: function () {
        if (!navigator.camera) {
            alert('Camera API not supported');
        }

        navigator.camera.getPicture( app.cameraSuccess, app.cameraError, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
        });

    },

    cameraSuccess: function (imageData) {
        console.log('cameraSuccess: '+imageData);

        app.movePhoto( imageData );
    },

    movePhoto: function (file){
        alert(file);
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI( file , app.resolveOnSuccess, app.resOnError);
    },

    resolveOnSuccess: function (entry){
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTime();

        //new file name
        var newFileName = n + ".jpg";
        var myFolderApp = "my_folder";

        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {

                fileSys.root.getDirectory( myFolderApp,
                    {create:true},
                    function(directory) {
                        entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName, function(new_entry){
                            path = new_entry.fullPath;
                            url = new_entry.toURL();

                            console.log(path+"\n"+url);

                            alert( path+"\n"+url );

                            jQuery('body').append('<img src="'+path+'" />');

                        }, app.resOnError);
                    },
                    app.resOnError);
            },
            app.resOnError);
    },

    resOnError: function(error) {
        alert('Error '+error.code+': '+error.message);
    },
}
```

Comment: is this code you posted working now, after the plugin update? I have been having the same problem with extremely similar code. I just Removed the File plugin and Added the current File plugin version 1.1.0

Just looking for a heads up if you had to make any changes to this code to help me avoid unspoken and unrealized pitfalls. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**27/5/2014 UPDATE:** Version 1.1.0 was released since than, therefore no need to use dev branch anymore.

It's a bug in cordova: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6148

It's already fixed in dev branch. You can update to dev branch with those steps:

remove the plugin:

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file
```

install the plugin (we have to use the git syntax in this case):

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.git#dev
```

check the iOS build > Targets > Your app target > Build phases > Compile Sources 
add (if not added)

```
CDVFile.m
CDVLocalFilesystem.m
CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.m
```

Comment: we are a month and a half later. The current rev for org.apache.cordova.file is 1.1.0.  Do you know if this rev contains the fix or do I still need to go to the #dev version to gain the utility of this use case ? I did not see any comment in the 1.1.0 rev's notes. Thx.

Comment: I did not try, but it should be fine in 1.1.0. If you look at the commits history, you can see that they merged dev branch to master to release 1.1 - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/commit/e9efe65a4a0a8711ee5e212efa1757d534cd0fd3